# Can I get my grandad to write a review for university?

Tags: references, education

You always see the general "you can't list family members" when it comes to references, but what if you're working at a company where your granddad is also your boss? He has a different last name to me so it wouldn't be obvious. Would they ask if they are related or does it not really matter?

Comment: What sort of review are you talking about? This question might be better suited for [Academia SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Of course you can. Then when they find out they lied they'll kick you out. Great plan.

Comment: Is this general "you can't list family members" a hard-rule for the university you are applying to? Or is it something that you've read somewhere else and that appears to be a common rule?

Comment: Are you asking about a reference to a Univesrity application, such as for school? Or for a job somewhere? It's not really clear where you are applying and what your recommendation is for.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold pending clarification from the author about whether this is about applying as a student to a university (off-topic) or an employment application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Assumption:** This answer assumes that the "no family members as reference" is only a common practice for references, and that there is no hard rule specified for the university you're applying to. If there is indeed a hard rule, please disregard this answer.

This said, yes you can.

The only way for them to notice your family relationship is that your grandad mentions it. As long as you make sure that this does not happen you're fine.

And even if they were to notice it, he was your boss, not your grandad, when you were working for him. Just ensure that the review is strictly professional, as any review from any "normal" boss would be.

Comment: I highly recommend against this. This is essentially lying, and being found out later would not be good.

Comment: I do not think it is lying. What is important is the role held by the grandad, which is "boss" in this context.
But I agree that if the question is asked, whether directly or indirectly, the OP should answer it without hiding that his boss also happens to be his grandad.

Comment: It is lying if the instructions specifically say "you can't list family members" and you don't ask permission to use a family member who is also a boss.

Comment: The application asks for 2 references, I have a teacher giving me the other but if I don't use my boss/granddad then i only have one, who else should I ask

Comment: Agreed. I am under the impression that the OP is referring to the general common rule (or common practice) of references not to list family members. If it written and is a hard rule, then my answer does not apply. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd add that you could always ask them, being sure to mention that he is actually your boss. They'll probably be okay with it as long as you're up-front and professional about it.